# nginx rewrite a bunch of subdomains to domain

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have configured my first nginx server, and I have to redirect subdomain1.domain.com, subdomain2.domain.com and a few more to domain.com

I searched a lot about rewriting in nginx but couldn't find anything that works.
Thanks!

Comment: If you are just trying to rewrite everything to the main domain, I'd favour: `server{server_name subdomain1.domain.com subdomain2.domain.com; rewrite ^ http://domain.com permanent;}` - you can change `http://domain.com` to `http://domain.com$request_uri` to preserve the path. You can also use regex matching or a wildcard in the `server_name` (e.g. `*.domain.com`) if you have a significant number of subdomains.

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm. I'm going to dig deeper into nginx cause I really like it since I started working with it.

Comment: Nginx is great, but it is important to not approach its configuration the 'Apache' way - especially for rewrites. If you are just starting with Nginx, their Wiki is a great resource (although, occasionally missing information). Definitely read [IfIsEvil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) and [Pitfalls](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx only knows about the (sub)domains that match a `server_name` in a server block. Requests for any other (sub)domain will end up in the 'default' server block, if you have one setup.

You, therefore need to create a new server block that will match the subdomains you are interested in.

```
server{
    server_name subdomain1.domain.com subdomain2.domain.com;
}
```

You can also use regex matching or a wildcard in the `server_name` (e.g. `*.domain.com`) if you have a significant number of subdomains.

Within that server block, add your rewrite (essentially amounting to, anything hitting these subdomains should be rewritten to my main domain).

```
rewrite ^ http://domain.com permanent;
```

Put it all together, and you get:

```
server{
    server_name subdomain1.domain.com subdomain2.domain.com;
    rewrite ^ http://domain.com permanent;
}
```

You can change `http://domain.com` to `http://domain.com$request_uri` to preserve the path.